# Configuring CloudFront with WordPress gives ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap error

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am using AWS EC2 to host my WP site having cyberpanel (Litespeed Ent and LScache plugin). Using free Let's SSL certificate (certbot).

I tried to active AWS cloudfront CDN on my site but getting following error

- SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP in firefox
- ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH in Chrome

Below is screenshot of my various setting

**Origin Setting**
[image]

I am using Public DNS as my origin domain

**Distribution Settings**
[image]

Generated the SSL in AWS certificate and applied here. Added cdn.domain.tld as alternate domain name and added it as cname pointing to distribution  in route53

**Default Cache Behavior Setting**
[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Note: I have TLS v1.3 enabled in my Litespeed

Comment: Your configured alternate domain name looks like `cdn...` ... but is that the domain name you're typing into the browser when you get this error?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have added it as CNAME ALIAS to the cloudfront distribution url in Route53.
The error start coming on my site as soon as I update my A records to cloudfront distribution url.
Also, when I visit my cloudfront distribution url in browser it throws 504 error

Comment: I'm not sure whether you answered the question that I asked.  If your site is `example.com` and you point that name to CloudFront in Route 53, but in CloudFront you have only `cdn.example.com` configured as Alternate Domain Name, the SSL error is expected because your browser connects to CloudFront and tries to negotiate SSL for a hostname that you didn't configure in the Alternate Domain Name settings... so CloudFront eaaentially "pretends" to be unable to negotiate SSL (resulting in that error) since it sees the traffic as invalid/nonsensical.

Comment: Here what I have done in Route53. first I created CNAME Alias for `cdn.example.com` and pointed it to `dxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net`. Then I edited the A record for `example.com` and made it Alias pointing to `dxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net` (Removed the IP address of EC2 instance). My `example.com` domain have Let's SSL certificate generated from cerbot on EC2. While I also generated SSL in AWS certificate Manager and added it to Cloudfront (as shown in image above). I am missing something?

Comment: Have you tried analyzing the certificates using something like this: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the Solution. I was doing some mistakes.

I have SSL certificate for mydomain and its www version only. No wildcard SSL. And I was adding `cdn.mydomain.tld` as Alternate domain names which have no valid SSL.

So I changed Alternate domain names to `mydomain.tld` and `www.mydomain.tld` and it started working.

Also, the SSL certificate that I generated in ACM was wrong, I added `*.mydomain.tld` as domain name, But I had to add `mydomain.tld` also, which I did and it solved the problem

Hope this help someone and he/she does not make silly mistake like me

Thanks @Michael-sqlbot and Jeff from jeffreyeverhart.com for pointing me in right direction.